# Removing tooltip from highcharts heatmap series.

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I have been handed an app that uses a highcharts heatmap.  My product owner wants the tooltips removed.  I have consulted the documentation ( url: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.tooltip ) but the series tooltip doesn't have an enabled property that i can set to false.

Comment: add `tooltip: { enabled:false },` property

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the tooltip for **all series** in charts use `tooltip.enabled` property: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.enabled

If you want to disable it only for **one type of series in the chart** (e.g. heatmap) return `false` in `tooltip.pointFormatter`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.tooltip.pointFormatter